# New with google maps api and javascript - Toggling json data/layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Trying to work with some survey data (pulling the same json file for now) any ideas on how to toggle off my variable boundaries? I've tried the visible and overridestyle but can't seem to crack it.

```
// Call the variables for a new map

Boundaries = new google.maps.Data();
Road = new google.maps.Data();

// Set variable to load json files/data

Boundaries.loadGeoJson('StageBoundariesLayer.json');
Road.loadGeoJson('StageBoundariesLayer.json');

// Set style of the variables/layers


Boundaries.setStyle({
  visible: true,
  strokeColor: 'yellow',
  strokeWeight: 5 
});

Road.setStyle({
  visibility: true,
  strokeColor: 'red',
  strokeWeight: 1
  
});

Boundaries.setMap(map);
Road.setMap(map);

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', toggleBoundaries);

function toggleBoundaries(){
  if (Boundaries.overrideStyle.visible === true){
    Boundaries.setStyle.visible = false;
  } else {
    Boundaries.setStyle.visible = true;
  }
};
toggleBoundaries();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', toggleBoundaries);

function toggleBoundaries() {
  if (Boundaries.getMap() != null) {
      Boundaries.setMap(null);
  } else {
      Boundaries.setMap(map);
  }
}
toggleBoundaries();
```

Comment: Code-only answers can almost always be improved upon. Please add a sentence or two explaining your answer and how it solves the problem.